# Access parent activity's method from dialog

Tags: android

My project have a activity named MainActivity and a BrowserActivity extend dialog service.

MainActivity will intent BrowserActivity on application started.

I would like to BrowserActivity can access MainActivity's public method.

something like that:
Method on MainActivity:

```
public void chooseShare(Intent intent)
{
    try
    {
        startActivityForResult( intent , PICK_SHARE);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex)
    {
        Log.e("Share" , ex.getMessage());
    }

}
```

And i want to do on BrowserActivity :
(Pseudocode)

```
((MainActivity)BrowserActivity.this.getOwnerActivity()).chooseShare(intent);
```

I try to do that:

```
MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();
ma.chooseShare(i);
```

However, it not work, it throw NULLPointerException.

Because i need `startActivityForResult()` instead of `startActivity()` for callback result.

And i digg on SOF, i found `startActivityForResult()` should be start on `Activity`, but not `Dialog`.

thanks you.

Comment: You can't do like this. You should write that method into `BrowserActivity` class.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use `getParent()` if it's within the same project.

```
Activity parent = getParent();
if (parent instanceof MainActivity)
    ((MainActivity)parent).chooseShare(i);
```

Another option would be to bind it with an ibinder and use a service or implement interfaces.

[Services | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Comment: neither for AppCompatActivity!

Answer (score 1):

you can access all classes method like this:

```
Context context;

public ProceedDialog(@NonNull Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    //do something
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   //do something


}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

      ParentActivity activity = (ParentActivity)context;
      activity.method();


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question. And I found a partial solution.

The key is that **Activity is a subclass of Context.**

You pass the `Context` paraneter to the constructor of your dialog, right?

And most people pass it by using `this` of `MainActivity`.

So, I used the following codes to get `MainActivity` reference.

```
private MainActivity getMainActivity()
{
    Context c= getContext();
    if( c instanceof MainActivity)
    {
         return (MainActivity)c;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then you can call the desired method by

```
this.getMainActivity().chooseShare(intent);
```

In the dialog.

I tested this and it works!

Hope it helped you or forecomers.

(I saw the last modification date just now)